# I need to programmatically fill out a PDF form's radio buttons, can I do this in JS, go, or python?

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, go

I found pdf-fill-form for node.js and am using that well for filling out a PDF application that a client needs to match the user's online application.  The only issue is that the pdf has a few radio buttons, like for gender, and I get no response when I try and set the field "Sex" value to "Male" or "Female" even though those are the values.

```
  var vals = {"Sex": "Male"}

  pdfFillForm.write(sourcePDF, vals, { "save": "pdf" } )
    .then(function(result) {
      fs.writeFile(destinationPDF, result, function(err){
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Success Saving");
      });
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

It says clearly in pdf-fill-form documentation that it only supports text and checkboxes so I get it, but I can't find anything outside of Java or C#/C++ that can do this, and I really don't want to add another technology to solve what seems like a fairly common problem. Anyone know of anything? Or is there a work around?  Thanks.

Comment: Submit a pull request to `pdf-fill-form` with support for radio buttons, get it merged, go home a hero who's added new functionality with minimal breaking changes to open-source software. Or file a ticket and let someone else get around to it eventually.

Comment: Thanks, I think I actually got it to work for my first open source pull request.  Appreciate the motivation and attitude Akshat!  Now hopefully it gets pulled, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

I made the fix myself, actually wasn't to bad.  I just updated the pdf-fill-form code, and am waiting to hear back about my pull request, but if anyone needs it in the meantime, https://github.com/mttchrry/pdf-fill-form

Answer (score 0):

**My solution for python using pypdftk**

**Input PDF file**

The pdf file is created in `LibreOffice Draw`, using the File/Export As/Export as PDF..

The radio buttons of a group all have the same name, and no group name.
(It seems you get the same result if setting different names and the same group name)

On a machine having `pdftk` installed, run the following on your input pdf file containing at least two radio buttons in a group:

```
pdftk in.pdf dump_data_fields > fields.list
```

File fields.list should have a section like:

FieldType: Button
FieldName: radio_button_cooking
FieldFlags: 49152
FieldValue: 1
FieldValueDefault: Off
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: 1
FieldStateOption: 2
FieldStateOption: 3
FieldStateOption: Off

Meaning there are two buttons in the group, with the same name radio_button_cooking.
If you have more buttons in the group, the values continue with 4, ..

**Fill the PDF using pypdftk**

Possible values for the buttons are here either 1, 3, or 3. Or nothing for no selection.

```
import pypdftk

val_rare = 1 #guesswork to link values to options
val_medium = 2
val_welldone = 3
fields = {
    'my_radio_button': val_medium,
}
pypdftk.fill_form("in.pdf", fields, "out.pdf", flatten=False)
```

File out.pdf should now have one of both radio buttons selected.
You have to do some guesswork to find out which button has value 1,  2 and 3.

If you don't want to use `pypdftk`, [there are other options](https://pypi.org/search/?o=&q=pdf%20fill%20form&page=1).